# when exactly is the SQLite DataBase initialised?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am playing with some SQLLite basics , and i try to creat a very simple DataBase from my Activity Class.The App runs ok, but when i go into the File Explorer of the Emulator ,  no DataBase is created , what is wrong here ?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}



class sql1 extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME="coordinates";
    public static final String TBNAME="show";
    private static final int Version=1;


    public sql1(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version){
        super(context, DBNAME, factory, Version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {

        String CREATE_TABLE ="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Names (Time VARCHAR,Long VARCHAR, Lang VARCHAR);";             

        arg0.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
        Log.d("TAG","Created Database");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main activity, Do this:

SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = null;

sql1 databaseHelper = new sql1(_context);

sqliteDatabase = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();

Answer (score 0):

i think the Problem could be that you use keywords like Long.  Assign another name. For Time i am Not sure but it can be a keyword too

Comment: hi, i tried replacing the keywords names but its still isnt created

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
            public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DbHelper() {

        super(dataContext, DB_NAME, null, 1);

        DB_PATH = "/data/data/" 
                   + dataContext.getApplicationContext().
                    getPackageName()+ 
                    "/databases/";

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if (!dbExist) {

            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }

    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        InputStream inFile = dataContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = inFile.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        inFile.close();
      }

      private boolean checkDataBase() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);

        return dbFile.exists();



    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    }
```

Comment: hi Saj , yes with this method it works , i have tried it before , but i want to make it work with the OpenHelper

Answer (score 0):

The `onCreate` call of `SQLiteOpenHelper` is not called until the first time your database is queried, more specifically the first time `getWritableDatabase` or `getReadableDatabase` is called on it.

Comment: db=this.getReadableDatabase();
     
   Log.d("TAG","Created Database"); but still not showing

Comment: Are you sure you're checking the correct location for your database? i.e. `/data/data/<Your-Application-Package-Name>/databases/<your-database-name>`

Comment: yes , exactly under the folder, but there is no "databases" folder there